# Recorrer array recursivo

Tags: php, array

Buenas, estoy con un problema explico mas o menos, necesito recorrer el array e ir concatenando padre e hijo, ahora necesitariamos que vaya concatenando solo si tiene hijos... supongamos que este es mi array:

```
$rows2 = array(
array(
    'id' => 142,
    'name' => "Cate 1",
    'slug' => "Cate 1",
    'childs' =>

        array(
            'id' => 143,
            'name' => "Cate1 nivel 2",
            'slug' => "Cate1 nivel 2",
            'childs' => array()
        ),
        array( 
            'id' => 144,
            'name' => "Cate1 nivel 3",
            'slug' => "Cate1 nivel 3",
            'childs' => array()
        ),
        array(
            'id' => 145,
            'name' => "Cate1 nivel 4",
            'slug' => "Cate1 nivel 4",
            'childs' => array(
                'id' => 144,
                'name' => "Cate1 nivel 5",
                'slug' => "Cate1 nivel 5",
                'childs' => array()
            )
        )
)),

array(
'id' => 145,
'name' => "Cate 2",
'slug' => "Cate 2",
'childs' => array(
    'id' => 146,
    'name' => "Cate2 nivel 2",
    'slug' => "Cate2 nivel 2",
    'childs' => array()
))
);
```

Si nos fijamos, el array de $rows2 tiene un padre con varios hijos, ahora bien, lo que intento es que me concatene solo 1 hijo con el padre, seria mas o menos asi:

```
Cate 1|Cate1 nivel 2
Cate 1|Cate1 nivel 3
Cate 1|Cate1 nivel 4
```

Y en el caso de tener mas de un nivel que verifique y me concatene tambien con ese nivel, ejemplo con el array id 145 que me quedaria asi:

```
Cate 1|Cate1 nivel 4|Cate1 nivel nivel 5
```

Eso si es que tiene mas niveles, tendria que poder tener una condicion, creo yo.

Esta funcion tengo hasta ahora...

```
$ant="";

foreach($rows as $row){
    array_walk_recursive($row, 'test_print', ["cadena"=>&$ant]);
    echo "\n";
    $ant="";
}

function test_print($item, $key, $ant){
    if($key == "name"){
        if(empty($ant["cadena"]))
            $ant["cadena"] .= $item;
        else
            $ant["cadena"] .= "|".$item;    
        echo  $ant["cadena"]."\n";      
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Entiendo que quieres pintar la "ruta" de los elementos hoja, los que no tienen hijos. Yo lo haría así:

```
function escribe_hojas ($item, $ancestors = []) {
    $ancestors[] = $item['name'];

    if ( count($item['childs']) == 0 ) {
        echo implode('|', $ancestors) . "\n";
    } else {
        foreach ($item['childs'] as $child) {
            escribe_hojas($child, $ancestors);
        }
    }
}

foreach ($rows2 as $row) {
    escribe_hojas($row);
}
```

He notado que tienes fallos de anidación en el array de ejemplo. Concretamente, los hijos de cada nodo (por cierto, el plural de *child* es *children*, no *childs*) deben estar en un array. Te edito la pregunta.